# VI editor Navigation similar to Eclipse

Tags: vi

I am used to eclipse/netbeans for coding. In eclipse If I want to go to the definition of a function I just hit F2 and it takes me to the definition and I can also return back to my current position. Does VI editor offer such flexibility? How do I do this in VI editor?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ctags` to create a tags file, then use <kbd>C-]</kbd> to go to the definition, then <kbd>C-T</kbd> to go back.  If you don't have a tags file, vim will try to find the definition without it.  You can also use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to go to its earliest use in the file, which is often the definition.

Comment: I don't think plain vi has tags support but you should try. To make the tags file, install the program `ctags`, go to the directory where you run vi, and type `ctags files` where ` files` is the list of source files.  Either way, I believe `gd` is in vi, try that.

Comment: And out of curiosity, what are you running on that you only have plain vi?